# how to check if OpenOffice is installed programatically using c#

Tags: c#, openoffice.org

how to check if OpenOffice is installed programatically using c#

Comment: Which OS? Windows, Linux or something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
     public  bool isOpenofficeInstalled()
        {


        //The registry key:
        string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey))
        {
            bool flag = false;
            //Let's go through the registry keys and get the info we need:
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //If the key has value, continue, if not, skip it:
                      //  if (((sk.GetValue("DisplayName")).ToString() == "OpenOffice.org 3.2"))
                        if((sk.GetValue("DisplayName")).ToString() == "OpenOffice.org 3.2")
                        {

                            flag = true;
                            ////install location ?
                            //if (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") == null)
                            //    Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - Install path not known\n"; //Nope, not here.
                            //else
                            //    Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - " + sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") + "\n"; //Yes, here it is...
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Place 4 spaces before the declaration `public bool IsOpenOfficeInstalled(){` so it becomes part of the code.

Comment: My LibreOffice installation isn't listed here (maybe I installed it via https://chocolatey.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gets the startup location of the default program to open a odt file.  As long as the file association has not been changed this works regardless of what version is installed.

(this is VB.NET)

```
Dim odt = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".odt")
Dim linkedValue = odt.GetValue("")
Dim linkedKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(linkedValue)
Dim openWith = linkedKey.OpenSubKey("Shell\Open\Command").GetValue("")
Dim O As String = CStr(openWith)

If O.Contains("swriter.exe") Then
// proceed with code
Else
// error message
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as in any other language? Search the known locations on the file system for the executable that launches open office? Check for libraries? Parse the output of "which openoffice"?

There are lots of options, and I'd say that most of them would not be reliable.

Comment: thanks. got the soltuion, i used registry to search openoffice instalation

Comment: @rajshades: Post the solution you found and accept it as correct answer